# Showing seaborn plot from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I need to store plots in a dictionary like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

test = dict()
test['a'] = sns.lmplot(x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", hue="species",
                       truncate=True, height=5, data=sns.load_dataset("iris"))
```

But how do I show that plot from the `dict`?

`test['a']` returns the plot object like `<seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid at 0x233011bfe80>` but does not show the plot itself.

```
test['a']
plt.show()
```

Does not show the plot either.

Any suggestions how to show the plot from the dictionary?

Based on the answer given I tried saving the `dict` to a pickle file, but showing the plot from pickle gives an error:

```
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

test = dict()
test['a'] = sns.lmplot(x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", hue="species",
                       truncate=True, data=sns.load_dataset("iris"))
plt.close()

# store dict in pickle file
outfile = open('test.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(test, outfile)
outfile.close()

# delete dictionary
del test

# load dictionary form pickle file
infile = open('test.pkl', 'rb')
test = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()

test['a'].fig
```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to suffice to call the associated `fig`:

```
test['a'].fig
```

works for me in a jupyter notebook.

btw: had to remove height parameter

It's not good to change the question entirely. However, it seems that your issue is only related to Jupiter!
Check this [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/231).

One solution is to prepend the first cell with `%matplotlib notebook`

Comment: Thanks, that works for me also! Do you know how to prevent the code line test['a'] = sns.lmplot(x="sepal_length", ...) showing the plot since I only want to store the plot in a dict to show it later?

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717877/prevent-plot-from-showing-in-jupyter-notebook). The last answer worked for me. I am assuming you are using a jupyter notebook

Comment: When I save the dict test to a pickle file and load it later, then test['a'].fig returns a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_figure'. Any idea how to solve that?